# Open Reveal Modal after 3 seconds

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

Anyone knows if it is possible to have a reveal modal window open after 3 seconds when a page is loaded, without pressing any button?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's entirely possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#myModal").modal('show')
                }, 3000);

        });


</script>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="sample">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnOK">OK</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>




</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may want to put that script inside the head or the body ;)